# AngularJS views' variables are not valorized

Tags: angularjs, socket.io

I'm trying to load data from a socket.io event and then push it inside an AngularJS view... The problem is that when the socket.io event is fired, the new row is inserted but {{message.username}} and {{message.text}} are empty. What am I doing wrong?

This is my code:

```
// Init AngularJS
var app = angular.module("ghat", []);

// Define room controller
app.controller("RoomCtrl", ["$scope", function($scope) {

    $scope.messages = [];

    $scope.pushMessage = function(message) {

        console.log(message) // returns {username: "FezVrasta", text: "<p>hello</p>"}

        // Push the new message to the messages array
        $scope.messages.push(message);
        $scope.$apply();
    };

    // Get new messages from socket
    socket.on("chat message", function(message) {
        $scope.pushMessage(message);
    });
}]);
```

This is the HTML:

```
<body ng-app="ghat">
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="room.html">
        <ul class="messages">
            <li ng-repeat="message in messages" ng-include="'message.html'"></li>
        </ul>
    </script>

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="message.html">
        <span class="username">{{message.username}}</span>: <span class="message">{{message.text}}</span>
    </script>
    <div class="container-fluid" ng-controller="RoomCtrl">
        <div class="room" ng-include="'room.html'"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**EDIT**: I've noticed that my code does not work only if I run it within my Node.js + Express.js application...

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.

I'm using Mustache as Express.js tpl engine, so it was render the NG variables when serving the page.

I've wrapper the NG views between `{{=[[ ]]=}}` and `[[={{ }}=]]` and the problem is fixed